# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4�⌷ 3⌷�9�⌷.�8⌷�9⌷" at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString

Tags: java, filereader

I'm having problems reading from a csv file which contains numbers with the format `#.##,#.##` those are randomly generated doubles (coordinates) wrote into the file as Strings by another program.

here's the part of the code that I use to read from the file and parse the coordinates:

```
    private void populateData() {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.data[0].length; i++) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sample.csv"));
            while (br.readLine() != null) {
                String[] split = br.readLine().split(",");
                this.data[0][i] = Float.parseFloat(split[0].trim());
                this.data[1][i] =Float.parseFloat(split[1].trim());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FastScatterPlotDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FastScatterPlotDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

}
```

it gives me a weird exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4⌷�3⌷�9⌷�.⌷�8⌷�9⌷"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:422)
at lab05b_Task2.FastScatterPlotDemo.populateData(FastScatterPlotDemo.java:86)
at lab05b_Task2.FastScatterPlotDemo.<init>(FastScatterPlotDemo.java:41)
at lab05b_Task2.FastScatterPlotDemo.main(FastScatterPlotDemo.java:107)
```

I don't know if it has something to do with the fact that I'm working on ubuntu and it's an encoding problem.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the strings you're trying to parse??

Comment: Use a csv parser library instead. Or read the number as `String` and parse it using a `NumberFormat` instead.

Comment: @HotLicks yes I debugged it the `split` array has `"439.89"` and `"651.67"`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried `NumberFormat` no luck, have no idea about csv parser

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that Peter has the answer.

Comment: Learn to use "od -c file" to see bytes in file.  This will help you troubleshoot encoding issues.

Comment: I used `getEncoding()` in the `FileReader` class, it returns UTF8

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen here is a part of the output from od -c command 
`0000000  \0   4  \0   1  \0   7  \0   .  \0   6  \0   1  \0   ,  \0   6
0000020  \0   6  \0   3  \0   .  \0   2  \0   1  \0  \n  \0   4  \0   3
0000040  \0   9  \0   .  \0   8  \0   9  \0   ,  \0   6  \0   5  \0   1
0000060  \0   .  \0   6  \0   7  \0  \n  \0   4  \0   5  \0   5  \0   .
0000100  \0   4  \0   ,  \0   5  \0   7  \0   4  \0   .  \0   7  \0   9
0000120  \0  \n  \0   5  \0   8  \0   1  \0   .  \0   1  \0   2  \0   ,
0000140  \0   3  \0   9  \0   9  \0   .  \0   2  \0   5  \0  \n  \0   5`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried CSVReader from OpenCSV and still the it gives me this weird strings with those rectangles

Comment: @enissay this clearly show that your file is in a double byte encoding so UTF-8 will not work,

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen to be honest I know practically nothing about encodings but changing the encoding from utf8 to utf16 got me pass this error.Thanks

Comment: If you run into these kind of problems frequently, it might be a good time to learn.

Comment: @Thorbj&#248;rnRavnAndersen  even though it is the first time I encountered such problem, I should learn about encoding .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have a UTF-16 encoded file.  You have to determine if it is UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE.  I would guess UTF-16LE first.  I suggest you set the encoding to match the file and you should read it correctly.  If you don't know what the encoding should be, ask the source of the file what it/they used.

BTW don't use `float` if you can avoid it.  Try `double` or `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: I have to use float since I need to work with JFreeChart FastScatterPlot class which requires floats as parameters

Comment: and the csv file was generated by me personnally without doing anything about the encoding, how can I set the encoding to match the file ?

Comment: `getEncoding()` returns `UTF8`

Comment: I only did set the encoding to UTF-16 didn't determine LE or BE but it got me pass this error .. Thank you